# Site column is not appearing on crawled properties - Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, managed-property, site-column

I'm trying to map a site column into a new managed property. I just created this column, I added it to a content type, and I edited a file just for setting a value on this new property. After that, I did a full crawl and I'm looking to create the new managed property, but when I try to map it from this site column, it doesn't appear in the mapping selection list. The name of the column site is propCrawl.

1. [It should be appearing here, but it doesn't](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UouM0.png)
2. [Also, it should generate the new property managed when it crawl the column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahpIP.png)

So the steps I've done are: creating a new column site, adding it into content type, writing a value from this property in a file, doing a full crawl and trying to map into a new managed property.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally I solved it with Powershell's script. First of all, the script created crawled properties naming everyone 'ows_' plus the name of every single column site. For metadata fields, the name of the crawled property has the prefix 'ows_taxId_' instead of just 'ows_'. After that, the script mapped every property (named like the site column) with these crawled properties.